# What is the problem with many-to-many relationships?

Tags: sql, tableau-api, data-modeling, business-intelligence

I feel like I have searched through the internet to find an answer to this question for quite some time now, but without success. Does anyone feel comfortable explaining why many-to-many relationships should be replaced with a bridge table?

Comment: Huh?  A "bridge" table is how you *implement* many-to-many relationships.  "replace" is not the right word.

Comment: Yes, but why is a bridge table required in the first place? Why not just keep the tables interac with each other directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably most (all??) RDMS implement a M:N relationship by creating a table  containing two columns with the FKs.
So there is no advantage to explicitely model the bridge table.

But in most realistic cases you want to store additional information (besides the fact of its existence) about the relationship instance, e.g. timestamp and user from the creation. That means that you need to model the bridge table anyway.